# Using shared memory under Windows. How to pass different data

Tags: c++, windows, shared-memory

I currently try to implement some interprocess communication using the Windows [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551.aspx) mechanism. I know that I need to create a file mapping object with CreateFileMapping first and then create a pointer to the actual data with MapViewOfFile. The example then puts data into the mapfile by using CopyMemory.

In my application I have an image buffer (1 MB large) which I want to send to another process. So now I inquire a pointer to the image and then copy the whole image buffer into the mapfile. But I wonder if this is really necessary. Isn't it possible to just copy an actual pointer in the shared memory which points to the image buffer data? I tried a bit but didn't succeed.

Comment: Murali Devi provides [working example code for shared memory in Windows](http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/win32/SharedMemory.htm).  His example uses memory, not an actual file, so it is exactly the case you describe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Different processes have different address spaces. If you pass a valid pointer in one process to another process, it will probably point to random data in the second process. So you will have to copy all the data.

Comment: @RandomNickName42: with the exception of shared memory, it is generally true for all common OSs.

Answer (score 9):

I **strongly** recommend you use [Boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). It has lots of goodies to manage this kind of stuff & even includes some special Windows-only functions in case you need to interoperate w/ other processes that use particular Win32 features.

The most important thing is to use [offset pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html) rather than regular pointers. Offset pointers are basically relative pointers (they store the difference between where the pointer is and where the thing pointed to is). This means that even if the two pointers are mapped to different address spaces, as long as the mappings are identical in structure then you are fine.

I've used all kinds of complicated data structures with offset smart pointers and it worked like a charm.

Comment: These are a.k.a. "based pointers", very much needed when 64-bit pointers are everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Shared Memory doesn't mean sending and receiving of Data. Its a memory created for number of processes without violation. For that you have to follow some mechanisms like locks so that the data will not corrupt.

In process 1 :

`CreateFileMapping()` : It will create the Shared Memory Block, with the name provided in last parameter, if it is not already present and returns back a handle (you may call it a pointer), if successful.

`MapViewOfFile()` : It maps (includes) this shared block in the process address space and returns a handle (again u can say a pointer).

With this pointer returned by `MapViewOfFile()` only you can access that shared block.

In process 2 :

`OpenFileMapping()` : If the shared memory block is successfully created by `CreateFileMapping()`, you can use it with the same name (name used to create the shared memory block).

`UnmapViewOfFile()` : It will unmap (you can remove the shared memory block from that process address space). When you are done using the shared memory (i.e. access, modification etc) call this function .

`Closehandle()` : finally to detach the shared memory block from process , call this with argument,handle returned by OpenFileMapping() or CreateFileMapping().

Though these functions look simple, the behaviour is tricky if the flags are not selected properly. 
If you wish to read or write shared memory, specify `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` in `CreateFileMapping()`.

Whenever you wish to access shared memory after creating it successfully, use `FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS` in `MapViewOfFile()`.

It is better to specify `FALSE` (do not inherit handle from parent process) in `OpenFileMapping()` as it will avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You *CAN* get shared memory to use the **same address** over 2 processes for Windows.  It's achieveable with several techniques.

Using [MapViewOfFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366763(VS.85).aspx), here's the significant experpt from MSDN.

> If a suggested mapping address is
>   supplied, the file is mapped at the
>   specified address (rounded down to the
>   nearest 64K-boundary) if there is
>   enough address space at the specified
>   address. If there is not enough
>   address space, the function fails.
>
> Typically, the suggested address is
>   used to specify that a file should be
>   mapped at the same address in multiple
>   processes. This requires the region of
>   address space to be available in all
>   involved processes. No other memory
>   allocation can take place in the
>   region that is used for mapping,
>   including the use of the VirtualAlloc
>   or VirtualAllocEx function to reserve
>   memory.
>
> If the lpBaseAddress parameter
>   specifies a base offset, the function
>   succeeds if the specified memory
>   region is not already in use by the
>   calling process. The system does not
>   ensure that the same memory region is
>   available for the memory mapped file
>   in other 32-bit processes.

Another related technique is to use a DLL with a section marked Read + Write + Shared.  In this case, the OS will pretty much do the MapViewOfFileEx call for you and for any other process which loads the DLL.

You may have to mark your DLL to a FIXED load address, not relocateable etc.. naturally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Marshalling of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, it would be best to have the image data loaded/generated directly into the shared memory area. This eliminates the memory copy and puts it directly where it needs to be. When it's ready you can signal the other process, giving it the offset into your shared memory where the data begins.